# When will the shape/OLE layer update?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a shape with text "Now Loading..." and background color #000000 alpha=0.5, as big as FHD screen.

I was intended to show it when a time consuming function was executed by user (as you can see, load data from somewhere else and dirty works), and hide it again after vba finished its job.

But it doesn't show at the beginning at all, only show up and hide again like a flash after vba done.

Yes I used MsgBox to check all the way, really, only show up and hide at the very end.

QUESTION:

1) So is this only happening to me?

2) If (1) not, why is this happening? Do the shape/OLE layer only refresh at the end(*1)? Tech detail would be appreciated.

3) If I insist to have this shape do its job, possible in Excel 2007? And how?

4) Alternative solutions(*3)? Just don't tell me.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Now Loading..."
'balabala
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Finish!"
```

*1) What I mean "refresh at the end" here, is, Excel collects all shape hide/show events and do at one time. So if I keep hide and show the same shape at some time consuming function, it turns out to be blink blink~

*2) Example code below. The shortest one I could share. `'Notes` for you to understand what I trying to do, `MsgBox` to show you my checkpoint.

```
Sub Item_Genre_Reset_Revise()
'↓ Show the loading notification.
Sheets("Item.Genre").Shapes("OLE_Loading").Visible = True
MsgBox "I thought the shape would show now, but didn't."

'↓ Merge 3 pieces into 1 piece.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AJ5:AL37").Value = Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("Q5:S37").Value
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AJ38:AL70").Value = Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("V5:X37").Value
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AJ71:AL103").Value = Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AA5:AC37").Value
MsgBox "No. :("

'↓ Sort the mergerd one.
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item.Genre").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item.Genre").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AJ5:AJ103"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item.Genre").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AK5:AK103"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item.Genre").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AL5:AL103"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Item.Genre").Sort
    .SetRange Range("AJ4:AL103")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
MsgBox "No. :( :("

'↓ Reload sorted items from internal memory to 3 pieces, as to give up all revise too for another function.
Call Item_Genre_Escape_Internal
MsgBox "No. :( :( :("

'↓ Reset revise counter.
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("T41").Value = 0
MsgBox "No. :( :( :( :("

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'↓ Hide the loading notification.
Sheets("Item.Genre").Shapes("OLE_Loading").Visible = False
MsgBox "Now the shape flash!"
End Sub

Sub Item_Genre_Escape_Internal()
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("Q5:T37").Value = Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AJ5:AM37").Value
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("V5:Y37").Value = Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AJ38:AM70").Value
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AA5:AD37").Value = Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("AJ71:AM103").Value
Sheets("Item.Genre").Range("T41").Value = 0
End Sub
```

*3) Globe setting to every sheets.

```
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
Worksheets("Item.Genre").Protect Password:="******", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Thank you very much.

SOLUTION:

Add `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")` to each `Sheets("Item.Genre").Shapes("OLE_Loading").Visible = True` . The shape would show as designed but still got 1~2s lag. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my reply, and I believe that this is rather what you are looking for.
Indeed, I noticed that the shape doesn't show when you call another sub routine.
Introducing a "wait" of 1 second solves the problem despite.

```
Sub Shapes()

Dim oShape              As Shape


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set oShape = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes("Oval 1")
oShape.Visible = msoTrue

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Call Other_Sub

oShape.Visible = msoFalse

End Sub

Sub Other_Sub()

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

End Sub
```

Let me know if you get the expected result.

Comment: When checking your code, is this time consuming? I assumed you were dealing with long loops, but the shape probably flashes because I'd expect this code to be executed within a second... Perhaps I didn't get your question right. Try somthing like Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05") and see what this gives as a result.

Comment: This is the shortest one I can share.

Comment: I updated my reply, perhaps this may help you right, if I understood correctly this time.

Comment: It works. But strangely, still need 1~2s to show up the shape even it is the first code.

Comment: I have really really good PC, I am the owner of an art studio so you can imagine. Can't tested in all PCs but if one was licensed to office suit 2007 in my studio, worse than my one...

Comment: I believe you, but I can't help it... Of course there will be 1 second time lapse for the wait function built in.

Comment: Not that 1s caused by `Application.Wait`, the `MsgBox` will come first (and even the second one), and 1~2s then the shape. Strange right?

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be some very brief delay on it. As an alternative, you could also display a userform.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width`, then the shape get refreshed. Sample:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes("Oval 1").DrawingObject.Width = xxx
```